# How to access Outlook 2016 drafts written when I was offline?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I drafted a detailed email in Outlook 2016 last night while I had no internet access. I closed down as usual, expecting to send the email from my drafts folder the next day. My Outlook has two accounts, an Exchange account which is the one I was writing the email as, and an SMTP/IMAP account.

This morning, with internet access, on Outlook on the same computer, my draft email has gone. I can't find it in either drafts folder. It seems like Outlook might have looked at my online drafts folders, synced them, and deleted the local one I wrote last night.

Is there any way  I can retrieve this draft email?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I switched the search bar to "**All Outlook items**" and searched on a few less common words I remembered from the email, and it found the draft, which for some reason had been moved to a Deleted Items folder.